# SQL Function: convert variable from varchar into tinyint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

I created a function, where I put in 3 variables:

@yy int, @kW int, @Wert varchar(50)

Inside of this Function I insert the values into @return_variable.

I have problems with the @Wert when this looks like this: '14,15,1,2,4,5,6,7,27'

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[F_Work](@yy int, @kW int, @Wert varchar(50) )
RETURNS 
 @return_variable TABLE
(   Stunden int,
    kW int,
    Wert varchar(50)

)
AS
    BEGIN
        declare @Tag date;
        declare @wk int ;

            BEGIN

                 set @TAg = (select top 1 StartTime from [dbo].[Work]           
                 where  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, StartTime) = @kW and DATEPART( YY, StartTime) = @yy order by Starttime desc)

                Insert into @return_variable (Stunden, kW, Wert  ) 
                 select SUM(ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, A.StartTime, A.EndTime) AS float) / 60, - 0)) , DATEPART( ISO_WEEK, A.StartTime ) as KW, B.Wert     
                            FROM 
                            [dbo].[Work] A join 
                            [dbo].[Workload] B on A.TS_ID = B.TS_ID 
                            where 
                            A.TS_ID in (@Wert )

                            group by DATEPART( ISO_WEEK, A.StartTime ), B.Wert
                            order by 3,2

            END
    return
    END


--  select Stunden  from [dbo].[F_Work](2018,40,'14,15,1,2,4,5,6,7,27')
```

I get an error:
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '14,15,1,2,4,5,6,7,27' to data type tinyint.

How is it possible to input this value inside of the Function.

Comment: And what part of the error do you not understand?  You should not be passing lists of numbers as strings.  Look into defining table types to pass lists into stored functions.

Comment: `IN` does not work that way. There are [alternate approaches](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html).

Comment: The problem is, that I can't CAST inside of a function.

Comment: It would be easy to get an answer if you include the full SQL that is necessary to reproduce the case, including the create table. However the in is expecting a sequence of integers and you cannot pass a string with the sequence itself except in case you are composing a sql command as string to be executed using sp_executesql command with an OUTPUT

Comment: You would gain some definite performance benefits if you made this an inline table valued function. What you have here is multiple statements which usually performs even worse than a scalar function.

Answer (score 0):

In expressions like `where A.TS_ID in (@Wert)` the parameter is not "replaced" with it's string representation and the result executed. You can do this using dynamic SQL - construct your query as a string and execute it with `sp_executesql`.

If you are on SQL Server 2016 or newer, you can take advantage of using [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function and change your query to be something like that:

```
where A.TS_ID in (select try_cast(value as int) from STRING_SPLIT(@Wert, ','))
```

But the best solution is to just pass the list if values as a real list and not as a string of comma separated values. You can do this by defining a user defined table type with one column and make @Wert parameter to be a [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017):

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ListOfInts AS TABLE (IntValue INT);  
GO
```

Then change the definition of your function to be:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[F_Work](@yy int, @kW int, @Wert dbo.ListOfInts READONLY)
```

and then you can use it in your queries like that:

```
where A.TS_ID in (select IntValue from @Wert)
```

Comment: It sound good, but the input value ( @Wert ) is in SQL format a varchar, not a integer. Do I have to format it? I get the answer: Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with ListOfInts

Comment: Of course, if you change the type of the parameter, you should also change how you call the function! Just declare a table variable of this type `declare @Wert dbo.ListOfInts`, insert values there `insert into @Wert(IntValue) values(1),(2),(3)` and call the function passing this variable as parameter.

Comment: Do I have to split the values? declare @Wert dbo.ListOfInts
insert into @Wet(IntValue) values('14,15,1,2,4,5,6,7,27')
There is the same error

Comment: Yes, I showed it in the previous comment. You must insert the values like this `declare @Wert dbo.ListOfInts insert into @Wet(IntValue) values(14),(15),(1),(2),(4),(5),(6),(7),(27)`.

Comment: On SQL it works :-) How I can give the rights for ListOfInts? Normally its: GRANT select (or exec) on ListOfInts to USERNAME. In this case it doesnt works.

Comment: GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE::dbo.ListOfInts to USERNAME